# Vuetify: v-calendar @click:day not invoking the callback function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm implementing a `v-calendar` component and so far trying print the day clicked by user.

Followed: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/

I tried use a method by time:

```
@click:day
@click:more
@click
```

and all togheter, but none way works, when I click on some day the `viewDay` funcitons is not invoked.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="pa-5">
      <v-calendar
        ref="calendar"
        v-model="value" 
        :type="type"
        :events="events"
        :event-color="eventColor"     
        @click="viewDay"
        @click:day="viewDay"
        @click:more="viewDay"
      > 
      </v-calendar>
    </v-row>
   
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Reservations",
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      type: "month",
      events: [],
      mode: "stack",
      picker: "",
      eventColor: 'blue'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    viewDay({date}) {
      print('abc')
      print(date)
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you meant to use `console.log()` instead of print?

Comment: Yes, you is right. Problem solved, I was so usually with python that forget it. Also, I figured out that if use `print` on Javascript, the Print of browser is opened.